# Java Virtual Machine Launcher- a java exception has occurred - debug

Tags: java, jvm

I received an error when trying to run HP's Operations Orchestration Studio for the first time.

The error in question states "Java Virtual Machine Launcher, a java exception has occurred". Having raised a ticket with HP, they suggest this is a java problem rather than a problem with OO studio.

I have seen similar errors to this with Eclipse posted in forums and the solution being to delete the .metadata folder, unfortunately OO doesn't appear to have such a file.

I have also tried removing all versions of Java installed on my Windows 7 64-bit machine and tried installing different 64-bit and 32-bit versions of Java which no success.

[image]

Does anyone know a way I could debug this error in order to resolve it?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you set env variable `CLASSPATH` correctly?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, CLASSPATH currently isn't set. Do you recommend that this should be set to the same as PATH?

Comment: No. More details  are here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29